# Validation control inside formGroup inside formArray

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

How can I validate a control within a formGroup that is in turn within an Array.

In this case I want to validate **numeroCelular**

I have the following:

**component.ts**

```
    this.formContacto = this.fb.group({
      telefonos: this.fb.array([
        this.fb.group({
          tipo: [''],
          numeroCelular: ['', Validators.required],
          whatsapp: [],
          codigoCiudad: [],
          numeroFijo: [],
        })
      ])
    });

    errorNumeroCelular(i) {
      return ((this.formContacto.controls['telefonos'] as FormGroup) as 
      FormGroup).controls.numeroCelular.hasError('required') ? 'Ingrese un número de celular' : '';
    }
```

**components.html**

```
<mat-form-field appearance="standard">
  <mat-label>Número celular</mat-label>
  <input matInput formControlName="numeroCelular">
  <mat-error *ngIf="errorNumeroCelular()">{{errorNumeroCelular()}}</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
this.formContacto = this.fb.group({
  telefonos: this.fb.array([
    [this.createNewFormGroup()],
    [Validators.required])
  ])
});
```

The `createNewFormGroup()` method is creating a FormGroup as following

```
createNewFormGroup() {
    return this.fb.group({
      tipo: [''],
      numeroCelular: ['', Validators.required],
      whatsapp: [],
      codigoCiudad: [],
      numeroFijo: [],
    })
}
```

To access validation state of FormArray

```
get yourName(): FormArray {
    return this.formContacto.get('telefonos') as FormArray;
}
```

HTML template

```
<label *ngIf="telefonos.errors?.required">
  your msg.
</label>
<label *ngIf="telefonos.controls[i].get('numeroCelular').errors?.required">
  your msg.
</label>
```